# Why would sed not work in my bash script?

Tags: bash, sed

Here is my code. I simply want to copy some files and replace a line in my Makefile. The parameter $1 is just the name of my new .tex file.

```
#!/bin/bash                                
pwd="./"                                   
tex=".tex"                                 
pwd=$1$tex                                 
cp ~/TeX/matt.sty .                        
cp ~/TeX/mon.tex $pwd                      
cp ~/TeX/Makefile .                        

sed="sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g' Makefile > Makefile"           
$sed
```

I've the following error : `sed: 1: "'s/mon.tex/salut.tex/g'": invalid command code '`

ps: i'm using sed on Mac OS X. (so it's bsd sed)

Comment: What do you expect this to be doing?

Comment: Your source and destination file is the same. You can't do that.

Comment: Okay i've changed it to Makefile > Makefile.new

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use: `sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g' Makefile > Makefile`? That will run your command directly, no need to create a string and evaluate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to sed is literally `'s/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g'` (with single quotes). obviously sed cannot parse that as a command.

Removing the single quotes would solve that problem but redirection (`>`) still won't work.

Just run the sed command directly (what's the point of the `$sed` variable? i don't get it)

Note: to modify a file with sed, use `sed -i`. Redirecting to the same file you are processing won't work.

Comment: I'm some kind a noob with bash. I just want to "build" the command I give to sed. Here I just want to replace Mon.tex with the parameter 1 + .tex

Comment: `sed -i "s/mon.tex/$1$tex/g" Makefile` there is no need to create a variable.

Comment: With your command I get "sed: 1: "Makefile": invalid command code M"

Comment: @Matthieu Riegler: sorry I don't believe you. that should work just fine. `sed --version`? does it work with `-i .ext`?

Comment: like I sed above. I'm running the BSD version of Sed and the --version   option does not work on that version :/

Comment: Hum, with -e option your command works !  ================>  sed -ie "s/mon.tex/$1$tex/g" Makefile. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by the `'`(single quote).
And, the `'` is not a valid `sed` command.

#### Example:

```
$ echo="echo 'hello, world'"
$ $echo
'hello, world'
```

You can use **`eval`** command to `Quote Removal` further more:

```
sed="sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g' Makefile > Makefile.new"          
eval $sed
```

**Note:**

1. `>Makefile` will make your orginal `Makefile` empty! So change it to `Makefile.new`.
2. `eval` is evil. Try to use `sed` directly!

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler `eval` is `evil`. Try to use `sed` directly!

Comment: `eval` is evil, *please* do no not use it. If this is something new for you just search for this phrase..

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler You are passing a variable to eval raw. This allows arbitrary code injection. I could give you `; rm -rf /; ` as your input variable and delete your entire hd.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: It's quite dangerous and difficult to debug, too.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You've doubling up your sed command line:</strike>

```
sed="sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g'"
```

creates a `sed` variable. You then use this variable as a command:

```
$sed s/mon.tex$1$tex/g Makefile > Makefile     
^^^^---here
```

which effectively makes your command line:

```
sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g' s/mon.tex$1$tex/g Makefile > Makefile
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--var   
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- excess args
```

and now I see your question's been editted to remove that... so ignore this, I guess.

Comment: i've corrected my code. sorry, I only use one simple pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You say

```
sed="sed 's/mon.tex/"$1$tex"/g'"
```

Which creates a variable `sed` containing the string `sed 's/mon.text/foo.tex/g'`, presuming that `$1` is `foo` for the sake of example.

You then expand `$sed` unquoted and it becomes

```
sed ''\''s/mon.tex/foo.tex/g'\'''
```

Which includes a literal `'` at the beginning of your expression, as if you had said:

```
sed -e \''s///'
```

EDIT: To reiterate, your problem is that you're needlessly quoting your `sed` expression inside the variable assignment. Use

```
sed="sed s/mon.tex/$1$tex/g Makefile > Makefile"
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: How does that suppose to solve my problem ? Sorry but I don't get how to use it in my code.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: see the edit. I will note that yi_H's solution is correct. Mine will still fail in some cases.